# Counting no of elements which are less than mean and the greater than mean

Tags: standard-deviation, means

I am trying to understand, counting no of elements which are less than mean and the greater than mean using a formula.

```
 [2, 1, 2, 6, 5, 5, 6, 5, 8]
```

I think I can calculate the mean and find out number of occurrences of where each element is less than or greater than the mean.

Is there any formula for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "tendency towards high/low numbers"? Is it the same as "are the numbers in the list small or large"?

Comment: @MattiP My apologies. I updated the question.

Comment: You count the elements, not the number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

For cases with $n$ numbers in your list, there could be as few as $1$ and as many as $n-1$ numbers less than the mean; and similarly for the amount of numbers greater than the mean.  So I don't see how you could get a formula of the type you are asking about.